# Resolve "valid signing identity not found in xcode" without import and export

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, private-key

i have only apple id and password

And i need to upload the app

Checklist of task which I have done:

- Download distribution certificate
- Download distribution provisioning profile
- itunes detail for application upload filled up and status is 'waiting for Upload'

Error I am getting is "valid signing identity not found in xcode"

I can't import or export the certificates.
All i can do is from apple.developer.com account

To solve this i have Tried:

- Window->Organizer->Teams->Refresh

But doing so xcode downloaded Developer Certificate which i don't nedd, i just want to upload the app.

Is there any way i can solve this without import and export of .p12 certificate.

if i request another certificate signing request do i need to develop another certificates?

**EDIT**
I have added distribution certificate in my keychain, but it does't show it private key along with it.

Here is screen of this:

[image]

Comment: did you put the distribution certificate in your keychain ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem

Here are steps:

1. Request new CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest
2. provisioning profile -> edit
3. Change its certificate with newer one

This 3 steps solved my problem